# TI 83 keyboard to USB/raspbian?

Tags: raspberry-pi

Hi electrical engineers!
This is my first time posting, and I am really just beginning to explore basic concepts in EE.
That said, my project right now is putting a raspberry pi zero into a ti 83. I expect it to be pretty easy, but I'm not sure how to make the keyboard work with the pi. The ti 83 has a pretty normal capacative keyboard, and I was wondering what the best solution would be to get it working as a keyboard for the pi. I have access to my universitys pcb printer, soldering station etc.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! You're going to need to do more work at researching how that keyboard matrix works. It likely uses carbon-resistive rubber domes and circuit board fingers to implement the keypad. Interfacing with this won't be much fun, I don't think. Another major problem would be interfacing with the screen, if that's a goal. From the scope of your project, remember to keep academic integrity and ethics in mind regarding your project's uses.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Did not expect such a detailed response in such a short period of time.

Answer (score 1):

Those keyboards are not capacitive as anyone would call them. It is a keyboard matrix with conductive carbon on the rubber pushbutton, called "[Silicone Rubber Keypads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicone_rubber_keypad)".

The two ways you can get this going is either wire into the existing pcb matrix, or use a custom pcb. Both would normally go to either a USB keyboard you have hacked up, taking consideration for the existing matrix's pinout/connections, or make your own, with like a usb enable arduino or similar. A USB keyboard matrix is not a trivial project, but easy enough with the number of projects on the web. Google `v-usb keyboard matrix`.

For example, someone [hacked a Game Boy into a TI-83 case](http://www.markbowers.org/gameboy-ti83/), and reused the buttons:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hope this isn't too late but I am doing something similar.  The keys on the 83 are arranged in a 8X7 matrix, as shown in this schematic I made [here](https://easyeda.com/AlexLynd/TI_83_Mini_Computer-f357c19627bb47e78d691e2d4e9cdb6a).  The rectangles are the solder pads that TI put on the PCB.  (I am not finished with the project).  I am using the keys as a keyboard through this method:  wire it to a 32u4 Arduino to inject keystrokes to the raspberry pi over USB.  You can use something like the [Teensy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NC43256), or as I did, use the Adafruit Trinket with an MCP (uneccessary, but cheaper).